# Power before, no power after fan installation?

Tags: ceiling-fan

I'm trying to install a ceiling fan with a wireless remote receiver, but I'm having issues with power/connection. Tested power from the Wall with a pen-style tester which showed power from Black. Wires shown below:

**Wall**: Black, Red, White & (Bare) Silver

**Wireless Receiver** **(Illumra Brand)**: Black, Red, White, Antenna

**Fan (Westinghouse 120V)**: Black, White, Blue, Green

FAN INSTRUCTIONS (*Wall* to Fan): *White* to White, *Black* to Black/Blue, *Green* to Green.

RECEIVER INSTRUCTIONS (*Wall* to **Receiver** to Fan): *Black* to **Black**, *White* to **White** to White, *Green* to Green

Bare silver wire was not connected to anything as i didn't know what it was.  Red wire from Wall not used so i covered with nut.  After installation, no power was coming from the wall anymore.  Not sure whats going on?

i'm a complete noob.

VIDEO: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wUUdSWbfaFQ
*(I wanted to test the line to determine if the line was the problem.  I added a light socket with a light bulb on and off to show you what I've been dealing with.)*

[image]

Comment: Did any breakers trip or fuses blow?  Is there a wall switch that controls this?

Comment: i turned off the breaker before installation, then turned it back on.  Tested the wires and nothing.  There is no wall switch.  After removing the wires and retesting the hot wire from the wall, its hot again.  Not sure if this happens because the fan is 120V?

Comment: Are you sure the "silver" wire isn't actually aluminum?  Better yet, can you get us photos of the wiring that's there?

Comment: I agree with ThreePhaseEel,pictures would help. But you said you you removed the wires from the hot wire and you see power there again. What are you using to test with? A meter, a light....? Also, is there anything else on this same circuit breaker? Did these other items work when you had the fan switch connected?

Comment: how do you add pictures?  i don't see an option for it on this site?

Comment: The "Add Picture" button is 6th from left above the editor textbox. It looks like a landscape picture of two mountains with the death star hovering above/behind them.

Comment: How many, and what color are the wires in the ceiling (at fan location)?  How many switches controlled the old light/fan?  How was everything wired *before* you started?

Comment: You don't list a connection to the red wire on the receiver instructions. This would normally be the switched output to the fan. Please verify  that you made a connection to the red wire on the receiver and update your question.

Comment: Can you post the instructions for your wall receiver?

Comment: The odds are very high that there is a wall switch which you haven't found. The reason there is both a black and a red hot wire in the ceiling box is so that the switch can turn off the light without turning off the fan. A cable like this one almost always leads directly to the switch. There could even be a switch for each wire or a switch and a dimmer. It is hard to make out what is going on in the video, but it almost looks like the red wire is live and the black wire is switched off at the wall. (Yes, I know this is an old post, but thought this might be useful to someone else.)

Answer (score 0):

Black from wall to Black on receiver
Red from receiver to black & blue on fan
All whites together

That is, IF you are sure you are showing us all the wiring.

Put that gizmo away.  It will mess with your head if you through CFL bulbs in the mix. CFL's carry current. Use a real tester.